# Let's commit to graduate

Tags: discussion, beta-status

It's already been [1,082 days in beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles), and I'd like to see our site graduating sometime in the near future. James Khoury proposed [aiming for the 1,337th day](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13194067#13194067) since beta started, and I like that idea, especially since it's only [in 255 days](http://www.convertunits.com/dates/daysfromnow/255).

[image: graduation goal]

I'd suggest increasing the voting going around so our users' reputation levels can increase and survive the privilege updates for graduated sites. Any suggestions on how we can prepare this site for graduation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the rules around graduation?

Comment: I think the main issue now (as per [area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles)) is the mean number of questions per day.

Comment: @plannapus I think so too. Maybe reaching 15 questions a day would spur the graduation date.

Comment: PCG is "special". I would be cautious about assuming that standard graduation criteria apply.

Comment: While I agree with @PeterTaylor, I think that a demonstration of sustained traffic is probably the biggest thing we can do to encourage the team to consider the site for graduation.

Comment: Do you realize that only 18% fulfilled their commitment? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4570/code-golf-programming-puzzles.  Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: @user2509848 I'd say that had something to do with it... a year or two ago. By now, it should not be a huge issue.

Comment: @Iszi OK, just wondering.  I'm still kind of new to this network, and am having a little trouble learning the rules and procedures.

Comment: @user2509848 It would seem so, but I think they fade away after 6 months. I joined during public beta, so I didn't have one.

Comment: Would we all of a sudden have Stack Overflow's privilege requirements? Because that'd basically make it so that only mods can do anything, the way it stands now.

Answer (score 31):

My suggestion is to **upvote more**. Currently we only have 2 users with over 10k rep, and just barely. I'd say only two people (five including mods) being able to vote to delete on an SE site is pretty bad.

Since deletion requires 3 votes, this means that **only mods** will be able to delete stuff!

So, if we want to get out of beta, just vote as much as you can. (Don't upvote bad or okay posts though!)

Comment: Too true, we need more rep. Have a +1 to help you along.

Comment: @Timtech Thanks, but there is no rep on per-site metas :P

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot. Too much Meta SO, I'm afraid.

Comment: +1 for the irony of it all

Comment: But is it that bad? Area 51 recommends at least "5 users with 3,000+ rep", and that's it. It won't be that bad if only moderators will be able to delete stuff.

Comment: @xfix There are currently 20 members with 10k+ reputation, so the main issue left is the fact that we are only getting 4.5 new posts per day on average.

Comment: @user248118 Keep in mind that numbers aren't everything. Even a site with "excellent" in all the Area 51 categories isn't guaranteed to graduate. (Especially considering that the A51 stats are very imperfect and need much improvement.)